# Looking for a script to show where a solution is active in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, stsadm, solution

I'm able to see that the solution is globally deployed (in CA) and I am also able to get the SolutionID with no problems.

**I'm looking for a way to show everywhere the solution is actually active and not just deployed.**

Currently using SharePoint 2010.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define "active", as in installed, or being used?

Comment: Active as in "activated" under the solutions page for each site collection. We have many that are deployed globally but not necessarily active on each site collection and that's what I'm trying to find.